# Trouble extracting a string from a character vector

Tags: r, stringr

I'm having trouble extracting certain matches from my character vector that I named classes using the `stringr` library:

```
classes = read_lines("https://statistics.ucdavis.edu/courses/descriptions-undergrad") %>%
  str_flatten()
```

A little snippet of `classes`:

```
...collaborative data analysis; complete case study review and team data analysis project. 
Effective: 2019 Fall Quarter.</p><h2>STA 190X—Seminar (1-2)</h2><p>Seminar—1-2 hour(s). Prerequisite(s):
STA 013 or STA 013Y or STA 032 or STA 100 or STA 103. In-depth examination of a special topic in a small 
group setting. Effective: 2018 Spring Quarter.</p><h2>STA 192—Internship in Statistics (1-12)</h2>
<p>Internship—3-36 hour(s); Term Paper...
```

I can clearly see that the word "STA 190X" is in my vector, but I can't seem to extract it:

```
>str_detect(classes, "STA 190X")
[1] FALSE

>str_extract_all(classes, "STA 190X")
[[1]]
character(0)
```

But if I copy and paste a section directly into the function, it works:

```
> str_detect("</p><h2>STA 190X—Seminar (1-2)</h2>", "STA 190X")
[1] TRUE

> str_extract_all("</p><h2>STA 190X—Seminar (1-2)</h2>", "STA 190X")
[[1]]
[1] "STA 190X"
```

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: What you see on screen is different from what your computer sees when it downloads the page via `read_lines` (Try view source or Ctrl + U in your browser). Right click the page and click inspect. Recommend trying again with something like `rvest` package.

Comment: Which package is `read_lines from`? `stringr` does not know it. What is the output of `str(classes)`?

Comment: @dario the output of str(classes) is `chr "<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if IE 8]> <html class=\"lt-ie9\"> <![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang=\"en\" dir="| __truncated__` . read_lines is from the `readr` package which is part of tidyverse

Comment: @John Can you check the output I showed

Answer (score 1):

We can do the processing with `rvest` and  extract the correct 'nodes'

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
read_html("https://statistics.ucdavis.edu/courses/descriptions-undergrad") %>%
       html_nodes("h2") %>%
       html_text() %>% 
       str_c(collapse = ' ') %>% 
       str_extract(., "STA 190X")
#[1] "STA 190X"
```

Comment: I copied your code, but my output was "NA", not "STA 190X"

Comment: @John Sorry, I can't reproduce it with `packageVersion('rvest')
[1] ‘0.3.4’
> packageVersion('stringr')
[1] ‘1.4.0’` on `R 3.6.2`

Answer (score 1):

## A simple solution:

You only have to adapt your regex a bit to match not only a space but anything that is not a letter or a number:

```
str_detect(classes, "STA[^A-z0-9]190X")  
[1] TRUE
```

## An explanation:

This is the weirdest thing:

```
match_position <- gregexpr("STA[^ ]*190X", classes)[[1]][1]
substr(classes, match_position - 10, match_position + 17)
```

The code above returns a matching of something that *looks like* the string 'STA 190X' but *is not*.

```
"r.</p><h2>STA 190X—Seminar ("
```

It can't be because there can not be a space between STA and 190X. If there *was* a space, the `gregexpr` would not have caught it (`STA[^ ]*190X` matches anything that does **not** have space(s) between STA and 190X)

## Edit:

The plot thickens:

```
grepl("STA[^[:punct:]]*190X", classes)
```

Returns **no** match, which I think means the mystery character is one of:

> [:punct:]
>
> Punctuation characters:
> ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~.

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace seems to be an issue. Try using `\\s` for whitespace and it should work.

```
readr::read_lines("https://statistics.ucdavis.edu/courses/descriptions-undergrad") %>%
    stringr::str_flatten() %>%
    stringr::str_extract("STA\\s190X")

#[1] "STA 190X"
```